# showing that $|x-y|^k$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ for $k \in (0, 1)$

Tags: general-topology

I have verified that all the other properties hold.  All I need to show is that the triangle inequality holds for this metric.  Here is what I did:

wts:

$|x-z|^k \leq |x-y|^k + |y-z|^k$

let $A = x-y$, $B = y-z$ and so $A+B = x-z$

$|A+B|^k \leq |A|^k + |B|^k$

since we can assume $|B|^k$ is nonzero, divide by it.

$|\frac{A}{B} + 1|^k \leq |\frac{A}{B}|^k + 1$

Now let $r = \frac{A}{B}$.

$|r + 1|^k \leq |r|^k + 1$

suppose $r>0$

$(r + 1)^k \leq r^k + 1$

$0 \leq r^k + 1 - (r + 1)^k$

let $f(r) = r^k + 1 - (r+1)^k$ 
then $f^{'}(r) = kr^{k-1} -k(r+1)^{k-1}$

The lowest value attained by $f(r)$ is $0$ and the deriv. is positive everywhere for $r>0$ so the function is increasing.  Thus we can say that in this case the triangle inequality defined above holds.

Now what about the case when $r<0$?  How can we do this?

Comment: What you can do is show that you can assume $|r|\leq 1$, and then when $r<0$, you have $|r+1| \leq 1$, and so $|r+1|^k \leq 1 < 1 + |r|^k$

Comment: I suggest you take a slightly different route. By the monotonicity of $x\mapsto x^k$, you have $\lvert x-z\rvert^k \leqslant (\lvert x-y\rvert + \lvert y-z\rvert)^k$. So it suffices to show $(a+b)^k \leqslant a^k + b^k$ for $a, b \geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $r <0$ set $s=-r>0$.

Then 
$$|r + 1|^k =|1-s|^k <|1+s|^k \leq |s|^k + 1=|r|^k+1$$

Answer (score 1):

This is in relation to Daniels comment.

You can get this result from a more general inequality. Let $k \in (0,1)$ and $a,b \geq 0$. Define the function $f(a)=(a+b)^k - a^k -b^k$. Taking the derivative we get that $f'(a)=k(a+b)^{k-1}-ka^{k-1} < 0$. Thus, our function is decreasing hence we have that $f(a) < f(0)$ which gives us that $(a+b)^k \leq a^k+b^k$ and applying your substitution and using absolute values we get the triangle inequality for this metric.